# Alterar comportamento padrão de elemento p:confirmDialog

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Preciso alterar o comportamento padrão do elemento p:confirmDialog. Ao clicar em sim, ele deve completar a request passando um valor e ao clicar em não, deve completar a request passando outro valor.

```
<p:commandButton value="Consultar"  onclick="consultar.show()">  
    <p:confirmDialog id="consultar" message="Foi feito a venda de recarga para esse cliente?" header="Confirmação" severity="alert" widgetVar="consultar">  
        <p:commandButton id="confirmaBtn" value="Sim" oncomplete="consultar.hide()" action="#{notaFiscalBean.consultarNota}">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{notaFiscalBean.temRecarga}" value="1" />    
        </p:commandButton>
        <p:commandButton id="recusaBtn" value="Não" oncomplete="consultar.hide()" action="#{notaFiscalBean.consultarNota}">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{notaFiscalBean.temRecarga}" value="0" />
        </p:commandButton>   
    </p:confirmDialog>
</p:commandButton>
```

Mas essa solução não está funcionando. 
Alguém tem alguma ideia do que posso fazer? Obrigado!

Comment: Adicione o código da action do seu bean, também.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efetuei a mesma questão no Stackoverflow em inglês e tive a resposta por lá.

Se mais alguém precisar, segue o link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36504533/5535174